# How to subset dataframe based on multiple conditions?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df covering information from year 1998 to year 2020 like this

```
Country Indicator 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 ... 2020 
[1,] A a 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 13
[2,] A b 7 8 9 10 11 12 ... 19
[3,] A c 13 14 15 16 17 18 ... 25
```

To capture data from year 2001 to year 2020, I have tried to subset a dataframe by column names and execute  `df_subset <- df[, c('Country, 'Indicator', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', ...','2020)]`

1. However, I'm not sure whether there is an easier way to subset this dataframe by column names and the sequence of columns? e.g., combine df[,c('Country','Indicator')] with df[,6:25]
2. I want to transform df and make col. And this is my expected output

| Country | Year | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2001 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| A | 2002 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| A | 2003 | 13 | 14 | 15 |

Thanks for your any help in advance!

Comment: include data ie `dput(head(df))` and paste it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
reshape2::recast(df ,Country + variable ~ Indicator)
```

Comment: Thanks! @Onyambu Your method works. I have tried to include data by `dput(head(df))` and pasted the result here but failed. I think it could be large magnitude of my dataframe. It include 40000 observations and 65 variables.